# React - passing props to another component whenever component is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 2 components, one is `Grid` component where I show list of some data. Another one is `"functional"` component which contains logic like `sorting, paging, etc` which will be in every `Grid` component. `Grid` component can contain some own specific logic also.

My question is how I can pass props to `functional` component whenever something was changed in `Grid` component. Right now it only pass props for the first time `Grid` component is initialized, after that `functional` component works with old props which are nevew actualized.

`Grid` component is connected to redux store but I dont think it does matter here.

I am not sure if initializing class component via state is good approach, is there another way how to do it?

Code to grid component

```
type ProcessListProps =
  ProcessState.IProcessesStateType
  & typeof ProcessState.actionCreators
  & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

type State = {
    sharedFunctionality: SharedGridFunctions;
}

class ProcessList extends React.Component<ProcessListProps, State> {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
      this.state = {
          sharedFunctionality: new SharedGridFunctions(this.props)
      }  
  }

componentDidMount() {
      this.props.requestData(this.props.dataQuery);
  }

componentDidUpdate(oldProps): void {
      if ((oldProps.dataQuery.context !== this.props.dataQuery.context)) {
          this.props.requestData(this.props.dataQuery);
      }

  if (oldProps.sort !== this.props.sort) {
          this.state.sharedFunctionality.buildSortExpression();
      }
  }
..render - removed for brevity
}
```

Code for Functional component

```
interface ISharedGridFunctions extends IGridBase, IBaseFilterActionCreator, IBaseActionCreator {

}
export default class SharedGridFunctions extends React.PureComponent<ISharedGridFunctions,{}>{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("shared component updated");
  }

  pageChange = (event) => {
      this.setPaging(event.page.skip, event.page.take);
  };

  setPaging = (skip: number, take: number) => {
      this.props.setPaging(take, skip);
  };

  sortChange = (event) => {
      const dataQuery = this.props.dataQuery;
      this.props.setOrder(dataQuery, event.sort);
  };

  //build sort expression in dataQuery object which is sent to api calls
  buildSortExpression = () => {
        let expression = "";
        this.props.sort.map((sort) =>
            expression += `${sort.field} ${sort.dir}, `
        );
        expression = expression.substring(0, expression.length - 2);
        const dataQuery = this.props.dataQuery;

        if (expression.length > 0) {
            dataQuery.sort.orderBy = expression;
        }
        else {
            dataQuery.sort.orderBy = undefined;
        }
        this.props.setOrder(dataQuery, this.props.sort, true)
    }

    removeByKey = (myObj, deleteKey) => {
        return Object.keys(myObj)
            .filter(key => key !== deleteKey)
            .reduce((result, current) => {
                result[current] = myObj[current];
                return result;
            }, {});
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ProcessList` itself rerenders when something changes?

Comment: Yeah, for example when I change page, `pageChange` method is fired, then `setPaging` and it goes to my redux store and get fresh data and page is set to new one. But its working because its not affected by props.